# Sliding windows basing on the number of lines rather than duration

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Given a dataset conataining multidimensional data-points; each data-point is defined in a line

e.g., (this is a dataset of 5-dimensional data-points; there are 3 data-points...)

```
2;5;3.5;P;0
1;0;4.4;L;3
14;7;5;P;2
```

Is there a way to define windows based on the number of data-points (nb lines) of the dataset, rather than basing on times ?!

**what exists:**

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val inputsStream = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)).map(x => x.split(";"))
val windowStream1 = inputStream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(4)) //DStream.window(<window duration>, <slide duration>)
```

**what I want** is something like:

```
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, 1000) //I get each 1000 lines (data-points) in each RDD !!
 val windowStream2 = inputStream.window(1000, 800) //The size of the window is also 1000 data-points; and it slides by 800 data-points (this means that 200 data-points overlap between two successive windows) !!!
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For me, Spark Streaming only works with small batches of times and not with batches of a data number from a dataset. To do exactly what you are asking for, I think you have to process your data ahead Spark Streaming to send your 1 000 lines of data each time unit.